# How to filter queryset data with exact matching word?

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I am creating one Django project, here I define some fields like:

```
class Data1(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
```

and making input word in msg variable
msg = "hello"
I want to filter all message field strings in which the msg variable exists. when I am using

```
list_data = Data1.objects.filter(message__icontains=msg).all()
```

it's not giving me desire output is there any way to filter query objects with exact word match in strings.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `Data1.objects.all()` its the samq sql query as below:

`select * from Data1`

but if you want something like below:

`select * from data1 where message like '%msg%'`

you should write:
`Data1.objects.filter(message__contains=msg)`
without `.all()`

based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: no bro I still getting extra data after removing all(), I want, is there any word in the string or not and if exist then further process, '%msg%'  search all value if it exists in a word then I got extra objects like if I want to filter all object with "shi" word then this filter syntax also considering "shiv" word I want to separate both and want exact word exist queryset.

Comment: if you want exact word `shi` you should  filter without contains, and icontains is case sensitive, can you write you desire outout and output? @ShivShankarKeshari